# Qual a diferença entre Less e Sass?

Tags: css, sass, less

Qual é a diferença de cada um e vantagens e desvantagens?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Há um Gist em que as diferenças e especificidades são colocadas em detalhes](https://gist.github.com/chriseppstein/674726).

[Há também este documento em que se ponderam vários aspectos mais macro entre os dois padrões](http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/), que na avaliação final o SASS é superior, embora o LESS tenha várias coisas a seu favor. Recomendo ler também a parte dos comentários.

[Há ainda um padrão chamado Stylus, muito sucinto e bonito](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/), mas com pouca adesão até então, mas que merece atenção.

No mais, [há pelo menos 8 pré-processadores de CSS, conhecidos e semi-conhecidos, sumarizados aqui](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/8-css-preprocessors-to-speed-up-development-time). Vale uma leitura rápida.

De qualquer forma, é importante dizer que a escolha deve se basear também na quantidade de ferramentas disponíveis para pré-processar o CSS na sua tecnologia favorita. Por exemplo, o Bootstrap e o web2py tem suas folhas de estilo feitas em LESS. O Yeoman possui um suporte mais desenvolvido para SASS, e assim por diante.

Comment: O último link está fora no momento :(

Comment: Puxa, que pena :/