# Quais são as diferenças estruturais e de sintaxe entre Sass, Less e Stylus?

Tags: css, sass, less, preprocessador, stylus

Hoje em dia é difícil ver pessoas escrevendo "CSS à moda antiga" por causa dos pré-processadores que facilitam a escrita removendo repetições de código, e simplificação de sintaxe.

Gostaria de entender quais as diferenças (de sintaxe e eventuais vantagens/desvantagens) que eles possuem, se eles cumprem o mesmo  papel, ou se possuem uma abordagem diferente.

Comment: `+1` - Existe [uma outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31282/129) que refere somente Sass e Less, acho que Stylus é um elemento de comparação importante.

Comment: Antes de votarem para fechar por ser baseada em opinoes. A pergunta e bastante objectiva, pede uma comparacao analitica entre os 3 preprocessadores, nao pergunta qual deles e o melhor.

Comment: Não acho que ela seja baseada em opiniões, mas a acho muito ampla (várias perguntas em uma só).

Comment: se perguntar para dez pessoas qual seu pre processador favorito, você receberá onze respostas diferentes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *se eles cumprem o mesmo papel, ou se possuem uma abordagem diferente.*

Essa sua frase define o tom da sua pergunta. Vou procurar basear minha resposta em ambos os pontos citados.

**Eles cumprem o mesmo papel?**

Basicamente, sim. O papel do pré-processador é fornecer o ferramental necessário para que seja possível contornar alguns *problemas* recorrentes da [última especificação](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) do CSS. [Já existe um *draft*](http://css4-selectors.com/) para a próxima, que promete facilitar bastante a nossa vida, e quando a maioria dos *browser* já a tiver implementado, o cenário dos pré-processadores vai, com certeza, mudar bastante. Vale lembrar que `SASS`, `LESS`, `Stylus` tem como propósito gerar arquivo(s) `.css` que respeitem a terceira especificação. Então, quando o os seletores do `CSS 4` chegarem, o seu código vai continuar funcionando sem problema nenhum, mas algumas das *features* dos pré-processadores vão tornar-se obsoletas. Para efeitos de curiosidade, existem coisas como o [Post CSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss), cuja intenção é permitir que o desenvolvedor escreva código contendo os novos seletores e faça uma espécie de *downgrade* para o `CSS 3`. Não vou falar sobre isso pois não é esse o foco da resposta, mas [aqui tem um artigo](http://tableless.com.br/use-as-facilidades-do-css-4-hoje/) que trás o básico.

É interessante notar que esse cenário é mutável. Amanhã, o `CSS 4` vai estar aí, e existiram pré-processadores que irão *solucionar problemas* que deverão ser corrigidos na especificação 5, e por aí vai. Alguns dos principais pontos que os pré-processadores facilitam **hoje** são

1. Variáveis, *loops*, condicionais, ...

   `CSS` não é uma linguagem de programação. `CSS` é uma folha de estilos, i.e., uma série de regras que devem ser seguidas para a apresentação das `tags`. Essa folha é uma lista, e o *browser* a interpreta como tal. Isso significa que, sem os pré-processadores, quando era necessário atribuir a mesma cor para diferentes seletores, você tinha que rebolar para fazer uma jogada inteligente misturando os conceitos de herança (`inherit`) e cascateamento, mas eventualmente teria que declarar um *`color: #f09363`* em diversos pontos do seu código. E, eventualmente, esses valores mudam, e aí você paga todos os seus pecados fazendo essa modificação manualmente. Ou então, `sprites`. Na empresa que trabalho, usamos `sprites` para servir nossas imagens, e fazer o calculo das `background-position` na mão só serve pra atormentar o estagiário. Com pré-processadores, da pra resolver isso com um *loop*.
2. Manutenção

   Os exemplos acima já servem para mostrar que o `CSS` pode se tornar um monstro na hora da manutenção. Pré-processadores tornam esse processo muito menos doloroso.
3. *Frameworks*

   Existem *frameworks* construídos com base em pré-processadores que fazem coisas excelentes. O [susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) é um *framework* de grids agnóstico, construído em cima do `SASS`. O [Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/), além de trabalhar muito bem com *vendor prefixes*, consegue criar *sprites* pra você a partir de uma imagem. Bom, não?

A lista de vantagens é grande, mas tem até gente [dizendo que você não deve usá-los](http://blog.millermedeiros.com/the-problem-with-css-pre-processors/). Claro que isso varia de pessoa pra pessoa. O fato é que a ideia de todos os pré-processadores é a mesma: facilitar a vida do desenvolvedor. [Essa lista](http://www.sitepoint.com/6-current-options-css-preprocessors/) tem 10 pré-processadores diferentes, além dos 3 que são o foco da pergunta. Se você analisar cada um deles, vai ver que a proposta é a mesma.

**Possuem uma abordagem diferente?**

Sim. Falando especificamente dos 3 principais:

1. `SASS`

   `SASS` é escrito em `ruby`, e tem duas sintaxes diferentes, conhecidas como `.scss` e `.sass`. A primeira é equivalente a do `.css`, e a segunda é uma linguagem indentada, como o `Python`. [É o mais popular dos 3](https://css-tricks.com/poll-results-popularity-of-css-preprocessors/) e tem uma série de *frameworks* disponíveis. Vale apontar que as versões do `Ruby SASS` e do `LibSASS` [são levemente diferentes](http://sass-compatibility.github.io/).
2. `LESS`

   Foi originalmente escrito em `ruby`, mas mais tarde portado para o `JavaScript`. Pode funcionar *server-side*, como um módulo do `node`, é o único dos 3 [compatível com Rhino](http://lesscss.org/#command-line-with-rhino) (até onde eu sei) e, o mais incrível, [pode ser usado do lado do cliente](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage). Não sei porquê alguém faria algo desse tipo, sendo que onera mais ainda o lado do cliente, e não consigo ver nenhum ponto positivo nessa abordagem. Se alguém souber de alguma vantagem, diz aí.
3. `Stylus`

   Também escrito em `JavaScript`, o `Stylus` é o que possuí a sintaxe mais flexível dentre os três. Este código

   ```
   p
      color black

   span{
      color blue
   }

   div
      color: green;
   ```

   compila para

   ```
   p {
      color: #000;
   }
   span {
      color: #00f;
   }
   div {
     color: #008000;
   }
   ```

   Você pode omitir os caracteres especiais `{}`, `;`, `:` e fazer uma combinação dessas omissões que o `Stylus` vai entender sem problemas. Eu, particularmente, acredito que isto não seja muito inteligente. Se você se torna conivente com erros de sintaxe em uma linguagem, vai acabar portando isso para outra, e basicamente nenhuma outra permite esse tipo de coisa.

Em termos de variáveis, o `SASS` exige que elas iniciem com o caracter `$`. O `LESS`, por sua vez, determina o caracter `@`. Já o `Stylus` é (novamente) mais flexível, e permite praticamente qualquer coisa (cuidado com palavras reservadas). A única obrigatoriedade é um espaço entre o sinal de igual e o nome da variável e entre o sinal de igual e o valor. Ou seja

```
minha_cor = blue
```

é permitido, enquanto

```
minha_cor=blue
```

não.

De resto, eles são parecidos entre sí, uma vez que tem o mesmo intuito. Claro que cada um deles tem seus métodos próprios e suas particularidades, o que podem os tornar mais ou menos viáveis para um determinado projeto. [Neste link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sass-vs-less-vs-stylus-preprocessor-shootout--net-24320) você encontra uma comparação feita quase que exclusivamente em cima de sintaxe. E [neste último](https://csspre.com/compare/), uma tabelona comparando quase que tudo entre os 3. Caso você pense em migrar de um pré-processador para outro, [receba mais esta tabela](https://csspre.com/convert/)

Comment: 1+, excelente explanação, até agora a melhor ao meu ver, respondeu de forma objetiva e com bastante informações adicionais para expandir o conhecimento.

Answer (score 10):

Pré-processadores de CSS3 são linguagens com o propósito de ajudar
na criação de estilos compatíveis com todos os navegadores e com diversos
recursos para nos ajudar, principalmente quando temos CSS's enormes.

O mais importante é reconhecer a sintaxe, e para nossa sorte todos esses pré-processadores usam uma linguagem semelhante entre si.

**Sass e LESS**

Ambos usam sintaxe padrão CSS e isso faz com que ele se torne muito fácil.
Sass usa a extensão `.scss` e o LESS usa `.less`.

O código abaixo funciona no Sass ou LESS.

```
/* style.scss or style.less */
h1 {
  color: #0565CC;
}
```

É importante notar que Sass também tem uma sintaxe mais antiga, que omite ponto e vírgula e chaves. Embora este ainda esteja por aí, é velho e não poderá usá-lo para além deste exemplo.

A sintaxe usa a extensão de arquivo `.sass` e se parece com isto:

```
/* style.sass */
h1
  color: #0565CC
```

**Stylus**

A sintaxe para Stylus é muito mais detalhada. Usando a extensão do arquivo `.style`, Stylus aceita a sintaxe CSS padrão, mas também aceita algumas outras variações,
dois pontos e ponto e vírgula são todos opcionais. Por exemplo:

```
/* style.styl */
h1 {
  color: #0982C1;
}

/* omitor colchetes */
h1
  color: #0982C1;

/* omitir dois pontos e virgular */
h1
  color #0982C1
```

Usar diferentes variações do mesmo estilo também é válido, então o seguinte exemplo irá compilar sem erros:

```
h1 {
  color #0982c1
}
h2
  font-size: 1.2em
```

Cada um dos arquivos acima irá compilar para o mesmo CSS. 
Você pode usar sua imaginação para ver o quão útil pode ser para seu projeto.

Com essas técnicas você não precisará escrever a mesma cor ou padrão várias vezes, utilizando variáveis você consegue diminuir e simplificar muito seu código.

Não vejo vantagem em usar uma técnica X em relação a Y, vai do gosto do programador.

Mas uma coisa sem sombra de dúvidas é o ganho em relação a organização do código, como você monta seu CSS e trabalha nele.