# Agrupar código em uma linha

Tags: php, javascript, css

Bom, eu gostaria de alterar meu código CSS, juntando os parametros que são "juntáveis"

Por exemplo esse código:

```
{
    margin-top: -2px; -> juntável com MARGIN
    margin-right: 40px; -> juntável com MARGIN
}
```

os parâmetros **margin-X**, **padding-X** entre outros são juntáveis nessa formula:

**parâmetro: (TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM, LEFT);**

no caso ficaria assim:

```
{
    margin: -2px, 30px, 0, 0;
}
```

Como faze-lo em PHP ou Javascript esse script que faria esse processo?

Comment: Duas coisas: 1) compactar e otimizar é bom, mas se seu servidor usar gzip, muitas vezes o ganho é nulo, visto que após a compressão muitas vezes o stream acaba ficando praticamente do mesmo tamanho. 2) Você explicou bem seu pensamento, e sua intenção. Mas o site tem o foco de perguntas e respostas. Qual seria a pergunta, neste caso? A sugestão seria você ir desenvolvendo, e fazendo perguntas específicas conforme fosse tendo dificuldades. Aqui tem umas dicas de como fazer sua pergunta ficar relevante: [ask]

Comment: @Bacco creio que até pra quem for mexer no código futuramente, seja melhor pega-lo de forma limpa, acho esses `margin-X` sujeira.. A pergunta seria como fazer isso em PHP, não tenho idéia..

Comment: realmente seria muito amplo desta forma. Não que não seja uma dúvida relevante, mas é uma tarefa razoavelmente complexa, com muitas etapas lógicas. Começa de você ler o CSS, depois fazer o parse desse CSS, depois implementar a lógica para reagrupar os dados desse parse, e assim por diante. Seria ou o caso de procurar algo pronto (deve ter algumas boas alternativas nesse sentido) ou ir realmente desenvolvendo cada uma das etapas, e perguntando em separado cada uma delas assim que você dominasse o passo anterior.

Comment: Leia [Melhores práticas para aumentar a performance do site (em inglês)](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) para aprender o que realmente pode fazer uma diferença e algumas coisas não tão significantes

Comment: Em `primeiro pega o código dentro de {}`, você teria que verificar a existência de media-queries etc que também usam chaves.

Comment: esse é o problema eu não sei fazer, não sou familiarizada com PHP

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101208/sass-vs-less-vs-stylus-diferen%C3%A7as-estruturais-e-de-sintaxe